# Extract everything before a particular string in python

Tags: python, regex

Let's say I have a string

```
s = 'ab@cD!.2e.cp'
```

I want to extract only `ab@cD!.2e` out of it. I am trying this:

```
print(re.search(r'^(.*?)\.cp',s).group())
```

But still getting the output as `ab@cD!.2e.cp`. Can someone please tell me where I am doing it wrong and what should be the correct `regex` for this?

Comment: Why not just `s.split('.cp')[0]`?

Comment: or just `s.rstrip('.cp')`

Comment: @Idlehands Try that with `s = 'desktop.pc'`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann interesting, didn't know that [`strip()` functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) remove *all combinations* of the chars.  Was wondering why it would return 'deskto'.  Thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `re.search`, use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'ab@cD!.2e.cp'
print(re.findall(r'^(.*?)\.cp',s)[0])
```

Output:

```
ab@cD!.2e
```

Comment: Yes that's working. Can you tell me why `re.search` was not working?

Comment: @PushanSharma `re.findall` will extract the exact groups found in the string (`(.*?)`) bounded by the non-group regex. `re.search`, however, scan and find the first location of a match, and return the match object. See seb's answer above for proper use of `re.search` in this case.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Could you elaborate on why this is an inappropriate tool and what the appropriate would be?

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this throws an `IndexError` if the string was not found.

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to add 1 as parameter to group:

```
import re
s = 'ab@cD!.2e.cp'
re.search(r'^(.*?)\.cp',s).group()      # 'ab@cD!.2e.cp'
re.search(r'^(.*?)\.cp',s).group(0)     # 'ab@cD!.2e.cp'
re.search(r'^(.*?)\.cp',s).group(1)     # 'ab@cD!.2e'
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this throws an `AttributeError` if the string was not found.

Answer (score 1):

If it is really just about extracting everything before a certain string - as your title suggests - you don't need a regex at all but a simple `split` will do:

```
res = s.split('.cp')[0]
```

yields

```
'ab@cD!.2e'
```

Please be aware that this will return the original string if `.cp` was not found:

```
s = 'foo'
s.split('.cp')[0]
```

will return

```
'foo'
```